# Failed to recompile the instrumented code

Tags: c#, android, ranorex

I've a question regarding to APK instrumentation deployment, which in the Ranorex Instrumentation Wizard i've selected my Android test APK and it would show error message of "System.Exception: Failed to recompile the instrumented code"

I've saw some post in the forum suggest to add "-static -multidex" in the setting, but I still encountered the same error message as following.

Sorry that i can't provide the apk and i don't have access to the source code.

could you please help to provide me some hint about what might be wrong?
BTW i've tried the KeePass sample app and it could process the Ranorex Instrumentation Wizard without a problem.

i'm using Ranorex version: 7.1.3

thanks

```
System.Exception: Failed to recompile the instrumented code. See details for more information: W: invalid resource directory name: C:\Users\YT\AppData\Local\RanorexStudio7\RxEnv\Android\temp\decomp\res font
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [C:\Users\YT\AppData\Local\Temp\brut_util_Jar_5136869975010999316.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 19, --target-sdk-version, 26, --version-code, 1, --version-name, 1.0.3, --no-version-vectors, -F, C:\Users\YT\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL9019467108615197149.tmp, -0, arsc, -0, META-INF/android.arch.core_runtime.version, -0, META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_livedata-core.version, -0, META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version, -0, META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_viewmodel.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_animated-vector-drawable.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_appcompat-v7.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_design.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_recyclerview-v7.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-compat.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-core-ui.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-core-utils.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-fragment.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-media-compat.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-v4.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-vector-drawable.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_transition.version, -0, p12, -0, arsc, -I, C:\Users\YT\AppData\Local\apktool\framework\1.apk, -S, C:\Users\YT\AppData\Local\RanorexStudio7\RxEnv\Android\temp\decomp\res, -M, C:\Users\YT\AppData\Local\RanorexStudio7\RxEnv\Android\temp\decomp\AndroidManifest.xml]
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:496)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResources(Androlib.java:430)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:329)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:267)
    at brut.apktool.Main.cmdBuild(Main.java:230)
    at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:83)
Caused by: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [C:\Users\YT\AppData\Local\Temp\brut_util_Jar_5136869975010999316.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 19, --target-sdk-version, 26, --version-code, 1, --version-name, 1.0.3, --no-version-vectors, -F, C:\Users\YT\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL9019467108615197149.tmp, -0, arsc, -0, META-INF/android.arch.core_runtime.version, -0, META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_livedata-core.version, -0, META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version, -0, META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_viewmodel.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_animated-vector-drawable.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_appcompat-v7.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_design.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_recyclerview-v7.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-compat.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-core-ui.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-core-utils.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-fragment.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-media-compat.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-v4.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-vector-drawable.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_transition.version, -0, p12, -0, arsc, -I, C:\Users\YT\AppData\Local\apktool\framework\1.apk, -S, C:\Users\YT\AppData\Local\RanorexStudio7\RxEnv\Android\temp\decomp\res, -M, C:\Users\YT\AppData\Local\RanorexStudio7\RxEnv\Android\temp\decomp\AndroidManifest.xml]
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.java:441)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:482)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [C:\Users\YT\AppData\Local\Temp\brut_util_Jar_5136869975010999316.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 19, --target-sdk-version, 26, --version-code, 1, --version-name, 1.0.3, --no-version-vectors, -F, C:\Users\YT\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL9019467108615197149.tmp, -0, arsc, -0, META-INF/android.arch.core_runtime.version, -0, META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_livedata-core.version, -0, META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version, -0, META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_viewmodel.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_animated-vector-drawable.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_appcompat-v7.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_design.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_recyclerview-v7.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-compat.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-core-ui.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-core-utils.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-fragment.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-media-compat.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-v4.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_support-vector-drawable.version, -0, META-INF/com.android.support_transition.version, -0, p12, -0, arsc, -I, C:\Users\YT\AppData\Local\apktool\framework\1.apk, -S, C:\Users\YT\AppData\Local\RanorexStudio7\RxEnv\Android\temp\decomp\res, -M, C:\Users\YT\AppData\Local\RanorexStudio7\RxEnv\Android\temp\decomp\AndroidManifest.xml]
    at brut.util.OS.exec(OS.java:95)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.java:435)
    ... 6 more

   at Ranorex.Plugin.Mobile.Tools.Android.Instrumentation.ApkFileInstrumenter.CompileApkFile(String sourceApkFilePath, IPathService pathService)
   at Ranorex.Plugin.Mobile.Utils.BackgroundWorkerSupported.ExecuteBgwCode[TArg0,TArg1](BgwDelegate`2 methodDelegate, Int32 doneProgress, String progressText, TArg0 arg0, TArg1 arg1, BackgroundWorker bgw)
   at Ranorex.Plugin.Mobile.Tools.Android.Instrumentation.ApkFileInstrumenter.Instrument(String apkFilePath, Int32 port, InstrumentApkOptions deployOptions, BackgroundWorker bgw)
   at Ranorex.Controls.Instrumentation.Workers.AndroidWorker.Run()
   at Ranorex.Controls.AndroidInstrumentProgressPage.bgw_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with the resource directory 'res font'. I'm not sure if the APKTool supports spaces in directory names, but you can definitely update the APKTool by replacing the C:\Program Files (x86)\Ranorex 7.1\Bin\RxEnv\Android\tools\apkTool with the latest from [APKTool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) to check if the newer version supports spaces. Also the instrumentation flags are usually only necessary for multidex apps and or apps which exceed the 64k method limitation.